# Sharepoint Workaround for Mixed content (Insecure Script) Error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, jsom

I am using a client side script in a SharePoint page. Since the script is hosted in other server and delivered through `http`, I am getting a `mixed content` error in javascript console.

> Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure plugin resource. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So, I have copied the script from other network and placed it in my SharePoint page and the error has been resolved. But still the code has `<embed>` tags with link to `swf` files, which I couldn't host in the my SharePoint page and the Mixed content error is still there.

Upon research I found that we can't solve this issue unless the content is delivered over HTTPS or hosted in the same server.

Is there any workaround to fix this issue from script level without changing the SharePoint security settings.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.